# Ignore math symbols (want underscore in regular text)

Tags: symbols

I want to include the following expression without any changes in my LaTeX document:

```
RES_0.5_SE_5
```

If I just type like that, LaTeX wants it to be math mode because of the underscores. If I use

```
\verb|RES_0.5_SE_5|
```

the text has a different font.

Is there a command to just use ignore math symbols?

Thanks!

Comment: Escape the underscore with `\_` or use `\textunderscore`.

Comment: How about using \path from the url package and the configure url package to use rm style (see manual)

Comment: I guess the trick lies in the use of `catcodes`. A simple \catcode`\_=12 however does not print the underscore.

Comment: BTW: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)